# Why don't two forms on one page in WordPress work?

Tags: cognito-forms, wordpress.com

I would like to ask for advice about Cognito Forms and WordPress. I wanted to add two different forms on one page. But it doesn't work. So I tried to install the plugin and still nothing.

How can I figure out?

Comment: "Your plugin"?  Whose plugin is that?

Comment: https://cs.wordpress.org/plugins/cognito-forms/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The current Cognito Forms application in WordPress is adding the seamless embed code when you add a form to a WordPress page. Two Cognito Forms that have been added with the seamless embed code wont work correctly.

To correct this you can embed one or both of the forms with the iframe embed code that you can get by going to the forms Publish page, when signed in to Cognito Forms in the browser or in WordPress.